# Android studio - add array to arraylist? Or similar method to store value pairs/arrays?

Tags: java, android

This is sort of what I'm trying to do:

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add([1,2,3,4];
                list.add([5,6,7,8]);
                list.add([10,15,-58,39]);
```

Basically, I have four values that I want to store together in one row, but only temporarily so I don't want to create a data base. 
Then I want to send these value pairs to another method and access them there.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
//I send searchClause, selecArgs, and allHands (int) to a method that queries my db. From there I retrieve 4 values in form of a list. 
                //I then add these values (average, hands, hand percentage, win percentage) to four different lists. I then repeat this process undefined times.
                list = dbCalculations(searchClause, selectionArgs, allHands);
                avgArray.add(list.get(0));
                handsArray.add(list.get(1));
                handPercArray.add(list.get(2));
                winPercArray.add(list.get(3));
```

Then I send these arrays to a new method to inflate a table.

```
  tableInflater(actionsArray, handsArray, handPercArray, winPercArray, avgArray, tableLayout);
```

I can then access them with a for loop (actionsArray.get(i), handsArray.get(i).) and then direct them to the textviews in my table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < actions.size(); i++) {

        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tablerow_post_stats, null);

        tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.table_action);
        tv.setText(actions.get(i));
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.table_hands);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(hands.get(i)));
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.table_handPerc);
        tv.setText("(" + Integer.toString(handPerc.get(i)) + "%)");

        tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.table_winPerc);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(winPerc.get(i)) + "%");

        tv = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.table_avg);
        tv.setText(avg.get(i) + "$");
        if (avg.get(i) >= 0) {
            tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPositive));
        } else tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorNegative));

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }
```

I want to find an alternative/short cut to it.

Comment: why not a `int[][]`?

Comment: What is source of the list items?

Comment: Are you getting items from 4 different arraylist

Comment: Source of the items are calculations/db extraction. Each int stand for a value like price,qty of a given product. So I would add the products to the list. Then in the next method I inflate make a table out of each product row.

Right now I just add them to qty list, price list, year list etc. and then add to a table row by using qty list.get(0), pricelist.get(0).. etc. I only need to store the values to send them to another method as a package, so I don't want to create a Product class just for this purpose.

However, I feel I'm unnecessarily creating too many lists.

Comment: Updated my post to clarify.